# Unable to Display Rasa 2.1.2 Chat Widget Using Socket.IO in HTML Webpage

Tags: javascript, html, rest, socket.io, rasa

m trying to integrate Rasa 2.1.2 with a chat widget using Socket.IO in an index.html webpage. The Rasa server is up and running, and I'm receiving the initial message "Hello from Rasa: 2.1.2" in the browser. However, the chat widget is not rendering.

I've followed the official Rasa documentation and various troubleshooting steps, including inspecting network requests, verifying the WebSocket connection, and checking the server URL. Despite these efforts, the chat widget does not appear on the webpage.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.